# Problems with moment function

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Iam trying to change date locale. But ive got problems, because im in `.js` file, and i dont know how to use `<script src="js/moment.js"></script>` in it. Iam trying to change

```
var url = '?m=public&a=end_date&date=' + f.task_end_date.value;
```

this f.task_end_date.value date locale and format, with moment function to change locale - `, 'lt');` and to change format i need 2015/Jul/07 but in different locale it would be 2015/Lie/07. Maby someone can help me with it

Comment: could you elaborate you problem and whats with the url ?

Comment: Onclick this function makes the end date field same as task_start_date.value

Comment: are you saying u want to refer to moment.js from one of your scripts  and change the locale ?

Comment: It would be better to change the locale before that var url. Im not very good with javascripting, im new one, thats why im asking for help.

Comment: first of all you need to include moment.js in your webpage `<script src="js/moment.js"></script>` and then set the locale like this http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

Comment: I need to put all `moment.locale('lt', {
    months : " ... and etc` to the same page i putted <script src="js/moment.js"> HERE </script> this script yes? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83175/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-torresalgrande).